# When writing powershell script, I have to run it twice for any changes I made to take effect to code that's inside a function. Any suggestions?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, powershell-ise

Like the title suggests, When I am writing a powershell script in Visual Studio 2013 or Powershell ISE. If I make changes to the script, when I run it, the changes I've made don't apply until I run it a second time. Not just variables, but whole lines of code as well.

Here's a sample code that produces the issue:

```
Write-Output "Code Updates";
Test;

Function Test{      
    Write-Output "Code Doesn't Update";
}
```

If you change the text in both the Write-Output commands, only the one outside the function updates on the first run.

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @vonPryz basically I've noticed it only happens to code that's inside a function call. Everything outside of it updates when ran, but inside the function it doesn't update until the second time. I can provide my sample code in the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell scripts just read from top - down only. I had to declare the function first then call it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are calling the function before it has had time to re-declare the function and pick up the changes.

When testing, you can highlight the function and hit F8 (in ISE) to re-declare the function without having to re-run the whole script.

Best practices say you should have the functions towards the top, before any logic. Put the functions in a module file and import the modules on the first row.

Regards, Edwoli.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use code that does not exist. You say you are using Visual Studio 2013, which means you are a developer type or trying to be. Functions are just like Visual Studio references / libraries. You can't use the reference / library unless you load and instantiate it first.

Script languages read top down and loads for operation top down.

Any code that is to be used by later related actions to other code blocks, like functions or modules and their exposed functions and methods, must be loaded first.

If you want to use any PowerShell cmdlet, its module and thus its associate methods, functions, classes, etc. must be loaded (in memory first)

Any custom functions you write must be the first things loaded / read by the script.

See the below for additional guidance.

> Design Your PowerShell Functions to Be Reusable
>
> Here are a few things I try to think about as I am writing a function
>   that will be reusable:
>
> • Functions should be short and sweet. Functions should do one thing
>   and do it very well. If your function is implementing multiple layers
>   of processing and logic, you should probably break it down into
>   smaller functions. Excluding parameters and comments, I would suggest
>   that the main body of a function should rarely be more than 10 or 12
>   lines of code. If it is longer than that, ask yourself if the steps
>   can be broken down further.
>
> • Functions should be pipeline friendly.
>   Functions should take input objects from the pipeline and also write
>   objects to the pipeline. A reusable function should never use
>   Write-Host, unless you are writing a function specifically to format
>   some special format. Remember that something that is output with
>   Write-Host is not put in the pipeline.
>
> • Use Parameters wisely.
>   Parameters should generally always have default values. For example, a
>   Get- function should always return a value. Parameters can be used to
>   allow a user to filter the output from the cmdlet. Think about how
>   Get-Process works. You can specify a particular process, but if you do
>   not, they are all returned. As you are writing your function and you
>   declare a variable, you should ask yourself if this is something the
>   end user may want to change. If so, provide a good default value that
>   most people will use, but allow the end user to change it if they want
>   to.
>
> • Functions should be named properly. Make sure that you use an
>   accepted verb and well thought out noun for your function. If you
>   adhere to these standards, it will be easier for others to incorporate
>   your functions into their code. Also, it will make your function more
>   discoverable and the end users will have a good idea of what to expect
>   when they see your function’s name.
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/05/20/design-your-powershell-functions-to-be-reusable
>
> Windows PowerShell: Build a Better Function
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh360993.aspx